# Compute Cholesky decomposition of Sparse Matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to implement [Reinsch's Algorithm](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfmdje-s3OAhVTzGMKHTBBDE0QFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emba.uvm.edu%2F~tlakoba%2FAppliedUGMath%2FReinsch_1967.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFHU9p-JQPjRf1uDznkvUAbgaus5A&sig2=uNhX_oJsi1RrIDF5vC5o6A) (pp 4). 
Since the working matrices are sparse, I'm using scipy.sparse module, but as you can see, Reinsch's algorithm needs the Cholesky decomposition of a sparse matrix (let's call it my_matrix) in order to solve certain system, but I couldn't find anything related to this.
Of course, in the same algorithm I can solve the sparse system using, for instance scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve, and then at the end of the algorithm use something like:

R = numpy.linalg.chol( my_matrix.A )

But, in my application my_matrix is usualy about 800*800, so the last one is very inneficient.
So, my question is, where I can find such decomposition?.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: google helps :) https://pythonhosted.org/scikits.sparse/cholmod.html

Comment: I'm aware of scykit.sparse, but: 
This is a home for sparse matrix code in Python that plays well with
scipy.sparse, but that is somehow unsuitable for inclusion in scipy
proper. Usually this will be because it is released under the GPL
Also, I can't install it for some reason.

Comment: Do you explicitly require the Cholesky decomposition? Or other decomposition (such as LU) would also work for you? If so, scipy has nice bindings to [SuperLU](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.splu.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.splu).

Comment: Probably the OP doesn't solved his problem by now but for others who come across this question: the scikit-sparse package can be easily installed with pip. https://pypi.org/project/scikit-sparse/

Answer (score 1):

For fast decomposition, you can try,

```
from scikits.sparse.cholmod import cholesky
factor = cholesky(A.toarray())
x = factor(b)
```

A is your sparse, symmetric, positive-definite matrix.
Since your matrix is not "Huge!!" converting it into numpy array doesn't cause any problem.

Comment: If you can convert the sparse matrix to a dense array NumPy solutions for determinant would be the most straightforward choice